# NSManagedObjectContext’s updated objects doesn't reset to empty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I’m new to Core Data and not sure if this is the correct behaviour.  Please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

My workflow is like this: once the moc is saved, it will trigger an upload of the data to CloudKit for backup and sync purpose.  It’s done through the context did save notification.

```
@objc func contextDidSave(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let context = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext else { return }

    if let insertedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> {
        print(“INSERTED \(insertedObjects.count) OBJECTS”)
    }
    if let updatedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> {
        print(“UPDATED \(updatedObjects.count) OBJECTS”)
    }
    if let deletedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSDeletedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> {
        print(“DELETED \(deletedObjects.count) OBJECTS”)
    }

    // Upload to cloud kit
    if context == self.privateContext {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.uploadObjectsAfterContextDidSave(notification: notification)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I’ve found that the moc’s modifies objects didn’t get reset.  For example, after I’ve modified and saved an object, the console output gives me

```
UPDATED 2 OBJECTS
```

Then I go back to modify and save another object, the console outputs

```
UPDATED 3 OBJECTS
```

And I've verified that the previous 2 updated objects are indeed remain within this set of objects.

What I’m expecting is that the “updated objects” will get cleared after each save, so that I only get the most recent changed objects after the last save, but it turns out not working like this.  Am I having a wrong concept?  Or did I do something wrong keeping the objects as “updated”?

My core data stack is setup like this:  `mainContext -> privateContext -> persistentStore`.  The contexts are saved by this piece of code.

```
func saveChanges() {
    // Save the main context
    mainContext.performAndWait {
        do {
            if self.mainContext.hasChanges {
                try self.mainContext.save()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Unable to save main managed object context")
            print((error as NSError).userInfo)
            print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    // Save the private context
    privateContext.perform {
        do {
            if self.privateContext.hasChanges {
                try self.privateContext.save()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Unable to save private managed object context")
            print((error as NSError).userInfo)
            print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I’ve tried `reset()`, `refreshAllObjects()`, `refresh(_: mergeChanges:)` on the privateContext after getting the notification.  But none of them helps.

Could anyone please shed some light on this.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would expect the behaviour you are hoping for too. Some thoughts: are you just observing the save notification on the private context? Or are you getting notifications from saves in both contexts, that could be confusing? Are you definitely observing the didSave notification rather than the objectsDidChange notification? Objects with relationships to the ones you’re updating can show up in the set of updated objects too. Then I would start looking at how your Core Data stack is set up to see if that’s causing an issue...

Comment: @ZoëSmith thanks for the reply.  Turns out the strange behaviour is because in the upload function the objects get updated again! (to store the CKRecrodID locally)  After removing this code the moc is working as expected.  Obviously there is still a lot for me to learn in CoreData + CloudKit.  Thanks again for your kind advice!  :)